# Saving Powershell command output to listbox

Tags: c#, powershell, user-interface, listbox

Trying to write some GUI program using *c#*.

I need to execute some Powershell commands *(Like Get-ContentFilterPhrase)* and add their output to list box.
Everything I was able to get right now is just a *(Collection)* in the first line of my listbox.

Could anyone describe how to do that right, please.

Here's one of my attempts:

```
var rulelist = new List<string>();
        var rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        using (var myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig))
        {
            PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
            var info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out snapInException);

            myRunSpace.Open();

            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddScript("Get-ContentFilterPhrase | Where-Object {$_.Influence -Match 'BadWord'}| Format-Table -Property Phrase");
                var results = ps.Invoke();
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    rulelist.Add(result.ToString());
                }
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add(rulelist);
        }
```

Comment: Because you're adding a bunch of strings, not "a" string.. if you want to add them add each one?

Comment: your adding the entire collection to the listbox so it is being displayed as the `System.Net.Generics.Collections` (or something like that) you will have to loop through each item in `rulelist` adding to your listbox exactly the same as you populated `rulelist`

Comment: `foreach (var result in rulelist)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(result);
                    }`
Does not seem to help