# Getting collection from powershell script in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Trying to get a collection of items as an output of PowerShell script within C# application, but it keeps returning me an empty collection.

*Results.Count: 0* after program execution.

(Exchange filter list is not empty, of course)

May someone explain what am I doing wrong, please?

Here's part of my code:

```
var rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        using (var myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig))
        {
            var info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out PSSnapInException snapInException);

            myRunSpace.Open();
            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                //Getting existing list of blocking rules
                ps.AddScript("Get-ContentFilterPhrase | Where-Object {$_.Influence -Match 'BadWord'}| Format-Table -Property Phrase");
                var results = ps.Invoke(); //Run PS script
                //Debug!
                MessageBox.Show("Script executed!", "Script executed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                listBox1.Items.Add(results);

                Console.WriteLine("results.Count: {0}", results.Count);

                // Is there something in results?
                if (results.Any())
                {// Looking at every object in collection
                    foreach (var result in results)
                    {
                        //Debug!
                        listBox1.Items.Add("Object");
                        //Looking at every property of every object in collection
                        foreach (PSPropertyInfo propertyInfo in result.Properties)
                        {
                            //Debug!
                            listBox1.Items.Add("Property");
                            //Writing propertyes to Console
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.Value));
                            continue;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                } else listBox1.Items.Add("Results're empty!");
```

Comment: `Format-Table` never ever returns the collection of items you are looking for. It is a formatting cmdlet, which is intended to use for output **formatting**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Powershell command output to listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791456/saving-powershell-command-output-to-listbox)